# Accessing duplicate feed tags using feedparser

Tags: python, rss, feedparser

I'm trying to parse this feed: https://feeds.podcastmirror.com/dudesanddadspodcast

The `channel` section has two entries for `podcast:person`

```
<podcast:person role="host" img="https://dudesanddadspodcast.com/files/2019/03/andy.jpg" href="https://www.podchaser.com/creators/andy-lehman-107aRuVQLA">Andy Lehman</podcast:person>
<podcast:person role="host" img="https://dudesanddadspodcast.com/files/2019/03/joel.jpg" href="https://www.podchaser.com/creators/joel-demott-107aRuVQLH" >Joel DeMott</podcast:person>
```

When parsed, feedparser only brings in one name

```
> import feedparser
> d = feedparser.parse('https://feeds.podcastmirror.com/dudesanddadspodcast')
> d.feed['podcast_person']
> {'role': 'host', 'img': 'https://dudesanddadspodcast.com/files/2019/03/joel.jpg', 'href': 'https://www.podchaser.com/creators/joel-demott-107aRuVQLH'}
```

What would I change so it would instead show a list for `podcast_person` so I could loop through each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Idea #1:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("https://feeds.podcastmirror.com/dudesanddadspodcast").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')

soup.find_all("podcast:person")
```

**Output:**

```
[<podcast:person href="https://www.podchaser.com/creators/andy-lehman-107aRuVQLA" img="https://dudesanddadspodcast.com/files/2019/03/andy.jpg" role="host">Andy Lehman</podcast:person>,
 <podcast:person href="https://www.podchaser.com/creators/joel-demott-107aRuVQLH" img="https://dudesanddadspodcast.com/files/2019/03/joel.jpg" role="host">Joel DeMott</podcast:person>,
 <podcast:person href="https://www.podchaser.com/creators/cory-martin-107aRwmCuu" img="" role="guest">Cory Martin</podcast:person>,
 <podcast:person href="https://www.podchaser.com/creators/julie-lehman-107aRuVQPL" img="" role="guest">Julie Lehman</podcast:person>]
```

---

**Idea #2:**

import feedparser

```
d = feedparser.parse('https://feeds.podcastmirror.com/dudesanddadspodcast')
hosts = d.entries[1]['authors'][1]['name'].split(", ")

print("The hosts of this Podcast are {} and {}.".format(hosts[0], hosts[1]))
```

**Output:**

```
The hosts of this Podcast are Joel DeMott and Andy Lehman.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the `feed['items']` and get all the records.

```
import feedparser

feed = feedparser.parse('https://feeds.podcastmirror.com/dudesanddadspodcast')

if feed:
    for item in feed['items']:
        print(f'{item["title"]} - {item["author"]}')
```

Comment: This is simple and very useful for many applications! Thanks for submitting this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `feedparser` I would prefer `BeautifulSoup`.

You can copy the below code to test the end results.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("https://feeds.podcastmirror.com/dudesanddadspodcast").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')

feeds = soup.find_all("podcast:person")

print(type(feeds))  # <list>

# You can loop the `feeds` variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm familiar with`lxml`, and considering the fact that someone has already posted a solution using `feedparser`, I wanted to test how`lxml` could be used to parse an RSS feed. In my opinion, the daunting part is the handling of the [RSS namespaces](https://podnews.net/article/additional-rss-namespaces-podcasting), but once that is resolved the task becomes quite easy:

```
import urllib.request
from lxml import etree

feed = etree.parse(urllib.request.urlopen('https://feeds.podcastmirror.com/dudesanddadspodcast')).getroot()
namespaces = {
    'itunes': 'http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd'
}

for episode in feed.iter('item'):
    # print(etree.tostring(episode))
    authors = episode.xpath('itunes:author/text()', namespaces=namespaces)
    print(authors)
    #title = episode.xpath('itunes:title/text()', namespaces=namespaces)
    #episode_metadata = '{} - {}'.format(title[0] if title else 'Missing title', authors[0] if authors else 'Missing authors')
    #print(episode_metadata)
```

**The execution time of the code above is close to 3x faster** compared to a similar solution with `feedparser`, reflecting the performance gains from using `lxml` as the parsing library.

Comment: Hi @Brenden. I've modified my answer so that it matches the scope of your question.